# AssetsManager giving null value in a Java Android project

Tags: java, android, 3d, augmented-reality, metaio

I have my object named `chair` in a folder (`Assets`). But when i debugged i was able to find that the `String` variable `filepath` is `null` for the following code.

```
filepath = AssetsManager.getAssetPath(getApplicationContext(), "TutorialInteractiveFurniture/Assets/chair.obj");
```

Comment: I don't know metaio, but I assume it should look like `"Assets/chair.obj"`

Comment: Its inside Assets folder in TutorialInteractiveFurniture folder. So its not the issue.

Comment: TutorialInteractiveFurniture folder is a folder _inside_ Assets or the other way round?

Comment: The path is right, TutorialInteractiveFurniture/Assets/chair.obj.

Answer (score 0):

Metaio resolves the path of your assets folder, so try only "Assets/chair.obj" should work!

Comment: you can create a folder inside Assets, "Assets1" for example and works too! and remember to call it inside the  loadContent() method